# How to calculate home widget width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is there any way to calculate home widget width at runtime. I want to add variable number of items(imageviews) based on it's width ,so I want to calculate widget's width in dp.

Comment: To save you looking at things I've tried that don't work: you can't solve this by using a custom view and overriding `onSizeChanged` (custom views not supported in widgets); I have yet to find a RemoteViews call which gives information about the view after the widget has been rendered (until `updateAppWidth` has been executed I get the impression that the remoteView itself doesn't know.)

Answer (score 1):

API v16 (4.1) adds a [onAppWidgetOptionsChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged%28android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) callback and as per the [App Widget guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider):

> This is called when the widget is first placed and any time the widget is resized. You can use this callback to show or hide content based on the widget's size ranges. You get the size ranges by calling getAppWidgetOptions(), which returns a Bundle that includes the following:
>
> > OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH—Contains the lower bound on the current width, in dp units, of a widget instance.
> >
> > OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT—Contains the lower bound on the current height, in dp units, of a widget instance.
> >
> > OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH—Contains the upper bound on the current width, in dp units, of a widget instance.
> >
> > OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT—Contains the upper bound on the current width, in dp units, of a widget instance.

Unfortunately, there is no clean alternative for pre 4.1 devices.